# Solspace Calendar For Craft CMS - Importing ICS Files

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm using Solspace Calendar for Craft CMS for an upcoming project.

The client has asked if they can initially import all of their events from an .ics file from Outlook.

I can't see anything in the docs. It doesn't appear to be a feature, however has anyone else come up with a solution to this? I'm sure it's not the first time it's been asked.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this something you still need? My team has an internal Craft Plugin capable of importing .ics files into Solspace Calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry, Calendar currently does not allow for importing of any events via ICS or other means.

*source: Kelsey Martens, Director of Software Operations*